# How to use Eclipse to view Java Stack on catch of an Uncaught Exception

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java program I am developing under Eclipse Kepler.  The program is throwing a NoSuchElementException.  I Setup Eclipse to catch the Exception, and when caught to Suspend the VM.  Which it did.  I see that the Exception was thrown from the ConcurrentLinkedQueue object.  However, there is no stack display so I can see who made the call to this object, that caused the Exception.

Is there a way to view the program stack so I can see who invoked this object?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a 7 year old version of eclipse?

Comment: Ok, it's Eclipse Kepler :)  My mistake :)

Comment: Try to use the debug functionality in Eclipse to step through the program execution. That might help!

Comment: How do you "setup eclipse to catch the exception"? Are you using an exception breakpoint or some other approach?

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks Greg.  That post captured how to view the Suspended Thread Call Stack which I wasn't sure how to do. Thanks!